# Icon file error when submitting app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Now , I am going to submitting my app. When I validate the app, I came across the problem below:

```
Icon specified in the info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: iTunesArtwork
```

The key of icon files in the info.plist is as below:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>iTunesArtwork</string>
    <string>Icon.png</string>
    <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-72@2x.png</string>
    <string>Icon-72.png</string>
</array>
```

And I have also added iTunesArtwork.png to my project (I have deleted the expanded name ".png")

I try deleting the value "iTunesArtwork" in the info.plist and the app passed the validation, but the app dose not have a icon. I don not know  does that matter. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the following:

```
<string>iTunesArtwork</string>
```

When your app is packaged and submitted to iTC, the **iTunesArtwork** file will be created and placed in the root of the .ipa package.

As for the icon not showing in Xcode Organizer when you submit, thats a bug I am thinking because my apps validate and submit properly too and they dont show the icon in organizer either.

Comment: "the iTunesArtwork file will be created"  do you mean that I should also delete the file iTunesArtwork?

Comment: Yes, it's not a file you need to provide yourself.